# Webpack javascript Heap out of memory - large number of modules

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm working a project using webpack 3.12.0 with Angular 4.3.1. The application is initially quiet big and due to a necessary modification, it got bigger and now I'm getting this error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of 
memory
1: node_module_register
2: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
3: v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory
4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject
5: v8::internal::MemoryReducer::TearDown
```

First of all, I noticed an increase of a number in webpack output when I run a simple build without uglifying and minifying, which i'm guessing is the number of modules compiled by webpack:

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

As you can see, we went from 1829 (+1815 hidden modules) to 2279 (+2265 hidden modules).

My first question: what does the number 1829 (and 2279) represents exactly ?

I tried to increase the max_old_space_size but it still does not work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you share your webpack config please ?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot due to the company policy. All I can say is this: the different between my npm start and build script is that the build runs **uglifyjs-webpack-plugin** and **babel-minify-webpack-plugin**

Comment: if you don't expose any company information you wont break the policies. And without it we cannot see what is going wrong.

Comment: you could use tenser-webpack-plugin and see if works. babel-minify is redundant at this point.

Comment: Well, It will be nearly impossible to help you without the config. Remove "sensitive" parts (I don't even know how you can have sensitive info in a webpack config) and publish that.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution.

The reason why the application got suddenly bigger is an import.

```
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Modified to:

```
import { BehaviorSubject  } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Now the application is back to its previous size and the build does not indur a heap overflow.

Comment: Was this because you imported from 'rxjs' as a whole and not from 'rxjs/...'?